# Pentaho reporting with dropdown parameter

Tags: reporting, datasource, pentaho, kettle

I am creating a report with PDI as a datasource, now i need to use a drop down parameter in my report.
for that i have added a JDBC datasource and wrote a SELECT sql that contains my dropdown list values and referred it in my parameter. but when i publish my report it says 'the query is not executable.' (If i change the parameter to a text box and my report works fine)

I have tried using another transformation with the same sql as a table input but the report still not opening and says 'Error -1'.

Report designer version: 3.6;
Kettle version: 4.3;

1. How can i use a dropdown parameter when i use a PDI datasource?
2. Is it possible to add multiple datasources and use in a single report like a PDI and JDBC?
3. or any other way to get a drop down parameter without bothering about datasources?

I have googled and not able to find any solution.

Comment: if for your textbox report works fine then connection must be fine , put the query you used for select box

Comment: SELECT 'OPTION1' AS DROPDOWN
    UNION
    SELECT 'OPTION2' AS DROPDOWN
    UNION
    SELECT 'OPTION3' AS DROPDOWN;

above is the sql i used for dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

yeah multiple data sources work fine. you need to check the server logs. Chances are either the connection is failing or the jndi is not setup?

Note that kettle running in prd in the bi server doesnt seem to be able to access the normal server data sources, so you must also setup simple-jndi.properties for some reason.